# Кастомная сортировка DataColumn в DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms

Имеется `DataGridView`, к которому привязана таблица через `DataSource`

```
dgvManInfo.DataSource = new DataView(ds.Tables["ManInfo"]);
```

К таблице добавлена колонка

```
ds.Tables["ManInfo"].Columns.Add("Дата рождения", typeof(string), 
                                 String.Format("IIF([Birthday] = '{0}', 'Не задано', " +
                                 "SUBSTRING(CONVERT([Birthday], System.String), 1, 11))", DATE_DONT_KNOWN));
```

предназначенная для удобного отображения даты или значения "не задано", когда дата равна заданному значению. 
Возникает проблема: сортировка теперь работает, естессно, по строкам! 
[image: Неверная сортировка DataColumn] 
Необходимо при клике на колонку `Дата рождения` сортировать по колонке `Birthday`. 
Через обработчик события `DataGridView.SortCompare` не работает, т.к.

> This event occurs only when the P:System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.DataSource property is not set and the P:System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.VirtualMode property value is false. 
>  https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.sortcompare(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предлагаю новую колонку создать типа `DateTime` - тогда у неё автоматически будет правильная сортировка.

```
ds.Tables["ManInfo"].Columns.Add("Дата рождения", typeof(DateTime), "[Birthday]");
```

Чтобы выводить, когда необходимо, значение "Не задано", можно обработать событие `CellFormatting`:

```
private void DgvManInfo_CellFormatting(object sender, DataGridViewCellFormattingEventArgs e)
{
    var dgv = (DataGridView)sender;

    if (dgv.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Дата рождения")
    {
        var dt = e.Value as DateTime?;

        if (dt == DATE_DONT_KNOWN)
            e.Value = "Не задано";
    }
}
```

Предполагаю при этом, что `DATE_DONT_KNOWN` имеет тип `DateTime`.

Дополнительно можно назначить желаемый формат вывода для колонки:

```
dgvManInfo.Columns["Дата рождения"].DefaultCellStyle.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
```

Comment: А быстродействие отображения не будет сильно страдать от этого?

Comment: @АлексейСтепанов - Думаю, обработка колонки с выражением `IIF...SUBSTRING...CONVERT` равноценна обработке события. Код можно чуть улучшить (ускорить), использовав индекс колонки, вместо имени (сравнение строк намного тяжелее сравнения чисел).